How to read user input in MIPS_o32 Assembly
so I have a bit of a problem, I am trying to read in a user input in MIPS_o32 Assembly. I have gotten it to read user input, but I have not figured out how to store it, I have seen videos of people just taking $v0 and storing it in $s0 but i think they are all using a different version of MIPS. The code I have so far is below.
.section .text

.global __start

__start:
    ; STDIN = 0
    ; STDOUT = 1
    ; STDERR = 2
    
    li $v0, 4003
    li $a0, 0
    la $a1, $v0 ; stuck here
    li $a2, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 4001
    li $a0, 0
    syscall

.data

msg: .asciz "Input Number: \n"

out: .asciz "Your number is: \n"

Any help or resource aides would be greatly appreciated!
Resources I am using:
https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=mips_o32
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf
https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~csci226/MIPS/summaryHO.pdf

"User input" is not something you can do from assembly directly -- it'a an OS service/feature, so doing it depends on the OS in use.

Literally 3 seconds after I posted this I found my answer, I can create:
var1: .space 3

In the .data section, if there is a more efficient way, please let me know.
so i have
.section .text

.global __start

__start:
    ; STDIN = 0
    ; STDOUT = 1
    ; STDERR = 2
    

    li $v0, 4004
    li $a0, 1
    la $a1, msg
    li $a2, 15
    syscall

    li $v0, 4003
    li $a0, 0
    la $a1, var1
    li $a2, 3
    syscall

    move $s0, $a1
    
    li $v0, 4004
    li $a0, 1
    la $a1, out
    li $a2, 17
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 4004
    li $a0, 1
    move $a1, $s0
    li $a2, 3
    syscall

    li $v0, 4001
    li $a0, 0
    syscall

.data

msg: .asciz "Input Number: \n"

out: .asciz "Your number is: \n"

var1: .space 3


I want to make sure you understand that what you're doing here is not just MIPS assembly, this is specifically Linux MIPS assembly.  Your program is nothing more than a series of 5 Linux system calls, and won't work on other systems.

@TimRoberts I do, I am just bouncing around trying to learn how assembly works. If you have a better suggestion I am all ears (or I guess eyes in this context lol), I would love some direction. Thought starting off with taking something simple like two user given inputs, adding them together then spitting them out. I've been programming for a few years (self taught), and understand the jist of assembly but not in detail.

Everyone learns differently, but what helped me at the beginning was to create some C programs, compile them to assembly, and look at what the compiler did.
